# Mongoose promise not resolving under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mongoose, promise, mocha.js

I have the following code that I am trying to write unit tests for using mocha. In some cases this is working as expected however in other cases the promise doesn't seem to ever resolve. Could you please help me solve this.

The code under test:

```
exports.inGroup = (group, user) ->
    return user.groups.indexOf(group) >= 0

##
# A promise returning function that returns the list
# of viewable channels for a user.
##
exports.getUserViewableChannels = (user) ->

    # if admin allow all channels
    if exports.inGroup 'admin', user
        return Channel.find({}).exec()
    else        
        # otherwise figure out what this user can view
        return Channel.find({ txViewAcl: { $in: user.groups } }).exec()
```

Now, when I test a non-admin user this works fine:

```
user = new User
    firstname: 'Some'
    surname: 'User'
    email: 'some@user.net'
    groups: [ 'HISP' , 'group2' ]

it "should return channels that a user can view", (done) ->
    promise = authorisation.getUserViewableChannels user
    promise.then (channels) ->
        channels.should.have.length(2)
        done()
    , (err) ->
        done err
```

However, when I test an admin user the promise doesn't resolve:

```
user3 = new User
    firstname: 'Random'
    surname: 'User'
    email: 'someguy@meh.net'
    groups: [ 'admin' ]

it "should return all channels for viewing if a user is in the admin group", (done) ->
    promise = authorisation.getUserViewableChannels user3
    promise.then (channels) ->
        channels.should.have.length(3)
        done()
    , (err) ->
        done err
```

In this case the mocha test times out:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
```

Comment: Just a random tip: Mocha supports promises out of the box in recent versions, you can just return the promise and the test will pass or fail based on whether it fulfills/rejects respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is dirty, but - if the assertion `channels.should.have.length(2)` fails, bad things happen. You don't have a `.catch` handler on *that* assertion which means the promise will be rejected.

Since mpromise (Mongoose promises) do not feature any good unhandled rejection detection, this will cause a silent failure of the promise and since `done` is never called in this case, Mocha doesn't know what to do. I strongly suggest using Bluebird over Mongoose promises as they are both faster (yes, even with Mongoose) and will not let silent failures happen like that and will track them for you.

The following, using the newer promise syntax Mocha offers in recent versions, should work.

```
it "should return all channels for viewing if a user is in the admin group", () ->
    promise = authorisation.getUserViewableChannels user3
    promise.then (channels) ->
      channels.should.have.length(3)
```

Comment: Great thanks, this helped. I couldn't return a promise to Mocha as I still needed to provide the assertion. What I did was wrap the body of the onResolve function in a try catch. This allowed me to figure out the underlying problem that was causing the assertion to fail. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanCrichton this will never happen if you use Bluebird promises instead. I'd look into it if I were you it saved me a lot of time. Glad I could help.